# ¿Cómo cortar la primera línea de la salida de un cut?

Tags: linux, bash, línea-de-comandos, cut

Quiero cortar la primera línea de esta salida ya que quiero solo la línea del archivo que más líneas tiene:

```
find /home/alberto/pepea/ -type f|xargs wc -l|cut -f 2,3 -d ' ' |sort -r

total

9 /home/alberto/pepea/1

7 /home/alberto/pepea/234

6 /home/alberto/pepea/2

5 /home/alberto/pepea/23ss
```

Answer (score 0):

Si sabes lo que contiene la primera línea puedes usar esto:

```
grep -v -E "^total$"
```

al final de los pipes de este modo:

```
find /home/alberto/pepea/ -type f|xargs wc -l|cut -f 2,3 -d ' ' |sort -r | grep -v -E "^total$"
```

donde:

- `-v`: Descarta la coincidencia que marque el patrón siguiente
- `-E`: Usa expresiones regulares para el patrón
- `^`: Indica inicio de línea (para no confundirlo con `/home/total` por ejemplo)
- `$`: Indica final de línea (para no confundirlo con `total/pedro` por ejemplo)

de este modo evitará mostrar las líneas que coincidan con ese patrón.

Y si no sabes lo que contiene esa primera línea puedes usar [tail](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tail.1.html) de este modo:

```
tail -n +2
```

al final de los pipes así:

```
find /home/alberto/pepea/ -type f|xargs wc -l|cut -f 2,3 -d ' ' |sort -r | tail -n +2
```

donde:

- `-n`: es el número de líneas a mostrar
- `+`: indica a *tail* que imprima todo a contar desde el número de la línea indicada a continuación. Así pues `tail -n +1` imprimiría toda la salida, pues empieza en la línea 1, pero `tail -n +2` todo excepto la primera línea, pues se la salta.

Ya dirás si te ha funcionado.

Comment: No es lo que quiero, ya que el head solo se queda con la primera linea y yo lo que quiero es cortarla

Comment: No te he entendido pues... pon un ejemplo completo de la salida que pretendes conseguir en la pregunta, pues no entiendo eso de cortar, ni por donde quieres cortar exactamente

Comment: o cuando dices cortar te refieres a eliminar?  que quieres eliminar?  la línea que pone `total`?

Comment: exactamente quiero eliminar la linea que pone total

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres cortar las primera n líneas de salida, usa tail:

```
tail -n +<linea desde el inicio hasta la que quieras+1>
```

Osea, si quieres que **no** se impriman las primeras 10 líneas, entonces:

```
tail -n +11
```

Por otro lado, si lo único que quieres es **la primer línea del archivo con más líneas**, se me ocurre un mini proceso de ETL:

1. Lectura: de todos los archivos
2. Enriquecimiento: creando templates de la forma:

   `<nombre archivo>:<n lineas>:<primera linea>`

   para cada archivo
3. Filtrado, para obtener el template del mayor

Todo esto se me ocurrió con:

1. `find`
2. `xargs awk`
3. `awk`

Algo así como un proceso map-reduce:

```bash
find files/ -type f \
    | xargs -l awk 'NR==1{first_line=$0}END{printf "%s:%s:%s\n", FILENAME, NR, first_line}' \
    | awk -F : -v greatest=0 '{ if ($2 > greatest) {greatest_template=$1":"$3; greatest=$2} } END{print greatest_template}'
```

En el segundo paso, para cada archivo, *awk* crea los templates con el formato `nombre archivo:n lineas:primera línea`, con las variables `FILENAME`, `NR`, y `first_line` guardada en la lectura de la primera línea.

En el tercer paso, le ordenamos a `awk` que constantemente compare el número de líneas de los templates leídos en el paso anterior. En el caso que el número de líneas leídos haya sido mayor que el anterior, entonces se actualizarán los datos del nombre del archivo y la primera línea resultante.

Ya al final, se imprimirán.

Como ejemplo, teniendo los sig. archivos:

```bash
head files/*
==> files/cuatro <==
foo
baz

==> files/dos <==
uno
dos

==> files/mas_lineas <==
foo
baz
foo
bar
quuz
quux
test

==> files/tres <==
uno
dos

==> files/uno <==
uno
(...)
```

Donde el archivo *mas_lineas* es el que tiene más líneas, el comando que propongo daría lo siguiente:

```bash
$ find files/ -type f \
        | xargs -l awk 'NR==1{first_line=$0}END{printf "%s:%s:%s\n", FILENAME, NR, first_line}' \
        | awk -F : -v greatest=0 '{ if ($2 > greatest) {greatest_template=$1":"$3; greatest=$2} } END{print greatest_template}'
files/mas_lineas:foo
```

Donde, el resultado es el nombre del archivo con más líneas, y su primera línea.

Si quieres solo la primera línea, métete al script de `awk` y tan sólo cambia la variable `greatest_template=$1":"$3` a `greatest_template=$3`

Answer (score 0):

Prueba a cambiar *args* por *exec*, de forma que *wc* se ejecute para cada línea y no muestre los totales. Si solo quieres la primera línea, puedes filtrar con *head -1* .

```
find /home/alberto/pepea/ -type f -exec wc -l {} \; |sort -r
```

O bien

```
find /home/alberto/pepea/ -type f -exec wc -l {} \; |sort -r |head -1
```